# What is the best way to get Ubuntu work on my new laptop

Tags: 13.10, hardware

I am going to buy a new laptop, and my old laptop is runing ubuntu 13.10 x64 and win7, can I just replace the hard disk from old laptop to the new laptop? Can ubuntu automatically recognize the new hardware?

Thanks,

Comment: You have good chances to do this, in my experience, previous versions (IE: 10.04) did a great work recognizing new hardware, unless the new laptop has certain blacklisted or proprietary devices (GPU's, etc.). You will need to run a test and check by yourself. The good news is that if you bring back the hard disk drive to your old laptop, it will work without problem after the testing. Good luck!

Comment: how to run the test? any linux command ?

Comment: Remove the disc from the old laptop and put it in the new. That's the only test you can do, IMHO. Good luck!